# ¿Cómo puedo guardar varios archivos sin tener que darle a guardar 1 a 1?

Tags: c++, qt

```
void MainWindow::on_toolImgs_clicked()
{
QPixmap pixmap;
    if(filtro==1){
        query=new QSqlQuery();
        QString campo=comboCampo->currentText();
        QString cond=comboCondicion->currentText();
        QString valor=comboValor->currentText();
        QString multi=comboMulti->currentText();
        QString campo2=comboCampo2->currentText();
        QString cond2=comboCondicion2->currentText();
        QString valor2=comboValor2->currentText();
        if(comboMulti->currentIndex()!=0){
             query->exec("SELECT id,icono FROM vertical WHERE " +campo+ " "+cond +" '"+valor+"' " +multi+" " +campo2+ " "+cond2 +" '"+valor2+"' ORDER BY id;");}
        else {query->exec("SELECT id,icono FROM vertical WHERE " +campo+ " "+cond +" '"+valor+"' ORDER BY id;");}
    }
    else
    {
        query->exec("SELECT id,icono from vertical ORDER BY id;");
    }

    QString fileName = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();



while(query->next()){

    fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"",query->value(0).toString(), "(*.png )");

    pixmap.loadFromData(query->value(1).toByteArray());
    pixmap.save(fileName);

}


    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
}
```

Intento Guardar las imagénes de la base de datos seleccionadas en la aplicación en el disco duro del usuario y que cojan la id como nombre de la imagen.Sin tener que guardar cada imagen una a una como hace ahora

Comment: Creo que ningún sistema operativo permite guardar varios archivos con un determinado nombre en el mismo directorio. ¿Te refieres a diferentes nombres?

Comment: Si , seria poder meterle este nombre* a cada uno y guardarlo en el directorio  QString fileName2 = *QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"",query->value(0).toString(), "(*.png )");

Comment: no falta agregar filename2 a la ruta?? actualmente solo tiene filename como ruta y eso es solo una carpeta. no hay que apnendarle filename2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo primero será pedirle al usuario que indique en qué carpeta se van a almacenar las imágenes:

```
QString basePath = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(0, ("Seleccionar carpeta"), QDir::currentPath());
```

Con esa carpeta de base ya puedes iterar sobre las imágenes y generarlas todas del tirón:

```
while(query->next()){
  QString name = QString("%1.png").arg(query->value(0));
  QString fileName = QDir(basePath).filePath(name);

  QPixmap pixmap;
  pixmap.loadFromData(query->value(1).toByteArray());
  pixmap.save(fileName);
}
```